# MySQL: One big query or multiple small queries?

Tags: mysql

For a bit of context I have a 4G RAM server and I have a cron job which loops through a MySQL table with around 15 million rows and does some processing.

To save memory I'm looping and selecting 200,000 records at a time and then repeating till I've been through every record in the table.

Is it quicker to do it this way or should I do less queries but select a larger subset each time?

Comment: Test the alternative approach you escribed and you will know the answer for sure.

Comment: If you can clearly identify batches of rows, then processing them separately is possible. The benefit is that you may use less resources if the query cannot be pipelined, at the cost of more programming and administration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what language/client library you are using.  MySQL has two different methods, mysql_store_result and mysql_use_result.  The former will read all rows from the server into memory before your loop, which can be more efficient, but is more expensive in memory.  The latter can defer getting rows until you loop over them.  Some clients allow choosing which is used.

In the end, if you want to know if and how much to batch your requests, you are going to need to benchmark your actual situation.